# What C++ function(s) support times in microseconds since year 1/1/0000?

Tags: c++, windows, time

I work in C++, visual studio 2012 and Windows 7.
I have 2 sets of data -
One with regular system times,
The other with times in microseconds since year 0 (the real 0, not 1970).
I have to find the correlation between the two sets -
So I need some function that can do the conversion.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need a function?  It's simple math.

Comment: _"...the real 0.."_ using which calendar, leap year, leap seconds, adjusted by mad monarchs etc...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar), the difference between these two epochs is 62,167,219,200,000,000 microseconds.  So you can just add/subtract this constant to translate between these two data sets.

This constant was computed using this [free, open-source, header-only C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    microseconds delta = sys_days{1970_y/1/1} - sys_days{0_y/1/1};
    cout << delta << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
62167219200000000µs
```

Comment: proleptic - that sounds like something from Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy :)